# Cassandra: Not enough replica error in single node cluster

Tags: java, cassandra, nosql

Over the weekend, we started seeing errors in Cassandra.  Essentially, complaining that it couldn't get enough nodes together for SERIAL consistency.

This appeared to be a problem with AWS vpn across regions.  So, to simplify, I dropped one the other node (There were only two nodes at the time).  I did this by removing the seed from the last remaining node's cassandra.yaml:

```
seed_provider:
...
- seeds: "single node ip"
```

I also ran `nodetool removenode` on the old node (which was showing a dead state).

So the topology is dead simple.  Application is a Java app which connects to the Cassandra node via Java API.

Below is the error I am seeing now:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replica available for query at consistency QUORUM (2 required but only 1 alive)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:45)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:34)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:182)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:66)
        ... 21 more
```

Which is the exact same error as before, except node we have `QUORUM` where we had `SERIAL` before.

---

I just tried setting the replication factor to 1:

`ALTER KEYSPACE my_keyspace WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };`

and restarted cassandra.  No change.

Also just ran `nodetool cleanup keyspace_name` based on answer below.  Also no change.

---

Just to be clear, the topology is this:

Java App -> Single Cassandra node

Still seeing: `Not enough replica available for query at consistency QUORUM (2 required but only 1 alive)`

Comment: Please describe the topology in more details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You mentioned you dropped a node.  Given you are using QUORUM and it requires 2 replicas, we can assume you have a replication factor of 2 or 3.   How many nodes do you have right now and what is your replication factor?  Based on your question I think you are indicating you have 1 left, but I wasn't sure.   If you only have 1 node and your RF is 2 or 3, you will never be able to meet quorum consistency.

You could [alter your replication factor](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/update_ks_rf_t.html) to 1 to resolve this, i.e.:

```
ALTER KEYSPACE keyspace_name WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
```

If you do this, you should also run `nodetool cleanup keyspace_name` on each node to get previous replicated data.

Another alternative is to add enough nodes to help you meet a QUORUM consistency level with your replication factor.

Comment: Same was my idea too - based on the error message "Not enough replica available for query at consistency QUORUM (2 required but only 1 alive)". Most likely there was 2 total nodes with the RF 2. I'd say add one more replacement node and run nodetool repair -pr on both immediately. And never have RF = number of nodes

Comment: I did set replication to 1, and after seeing your answer, ran `cleanup`.  Error persists...

Comment: That doesn't seem right, with an RF of 1, quorum only requires 1 replica.  Are you sure you made the correct adjustment? 'describe keyspace keyspace_name' will show your configured RF.

Comment: I know, it seems odd.  When I describe the keyspace I get: `CREATE KEYSPACE my_keyspace WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;`

Comment: What does nodetool status output?

Comment: Just an update on this.  I saw in my IRC logs that @mtyson got to the bottom of this.  His 'cache' and 'system' keyspaces still had the previous replication factors which was causing this issue.  mtyson, did I understand that correctly?

Comment: @AndyTolbert - That's right, if I remember correctly, it was the `cache` keyspace that was holding on to the Network topology, with a replication factor of 2.  Thanks for the reminder.  I'll add an answer asap (unless you want to :P)

Comment: @mtyson, feel free to add an answer since you found the solution :)

Comment: ALTER KEYSPACE keyspace_name WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 }; resolved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change QUORUM to ONE while using single node cluster

Answer (score 0):

**In addition to all,**

Check the cassandra  LOGS. "logs/debug..."

if you have too many tombstones at the node side. you should clean tombstones. for example
Log output :

***"ReadCommand.java:569 - Read 1000 live rows and 1272327 tombstone cells for query SELECT * FROM "***

Check the log levels also,